# Which type of page to use for a customized front page in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, panels

I am watching the following [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6zMcfTxkhc) on panels. The author is creating a content type for 'Home page', and later, a node view variant of node templates. He mentions that he is not 100% about this way of proceeding, but he is used to it.

The more I learn about this subject and the more I try to replicate this approach, the less I am convinced by it. Creating a content type for a home page seems like an heresy.

The panels dashboard offers to create panel pages, but also landing pages. It seems to me like a landing page would be enough (after setting it as the default front page), but would a panel page offer more benefit in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always tend to use the [Context](http://www.drupal.org/project/context) module.  Just set up a front page context that doesn't load all the unnecessary items (blocks, breadcrumbs or whatever) then have any node/panel you fancy as a home page without all the extra items that you don't need rendered onto the page.  It does seem slightly overkill to have an entire content type dedicated to one node though, I agree with that.

Comment: The context module for Drupal 7 is in beta2. Is it stable enough for production, or should I wait for a better release?

Comment: I've not had any problems so far.  Might be worth checking the module page/issue queue and see what stable release blockers there are (I've had a quick look and can't see any listed so I would imagine any critical bugs are gone/almost gone).

Answer (score 1):

The "homepage" word is abusive. It's not the home/landing page of your website. In the tutorial, it's just a layout. All nodes with the content type "homepage" will use this layout. That's all. And there might be a number of nodes "homepage".

If you want a real and unique homepage, that means no other pages have the same layout, then the way is to use a custom page (a landing page) and define it as frontpage (the "correct" term to say "homepage" in Drupal).

In short, there are two solutions for two different problems.